# Can I use both Macbook built-in GPUs on separate displays

Tags: display, thunderbolt

My Macbook has 2 GPUs:

- Radeon Pro 560 4096 MB
- Intel HD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Is there any way to use **"Radeon Pro 560 4096 MB"** on Apple Thunderbolt Display and the other one **"Intel HD Graphics 630"** on the Macbook itself?

Current situation:

[image: Macbook displays]